# ssis execute process task capture exit code into variable

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to capture exit code from an ssis execute process task into a variable. The exit code is a string, although the value itself is an integer,  value of 0 or 1 is success, other mean failure.

As far as I know I cannot specify multiple success values within the "Success value property", so I decided to capture the exit code into a variable, pass it to Execute script task and evaluate there whether the exit code represents success or failure.

I've set up a string variable to capture the exit code of my app, with type string.

Unfortunately, the value is empty after Process task execution, no matter whether I put my variable directly into StandardOutputVariable or into Expressions tab:

[image: ssis execute process setup]

On execution, in the Locals windows in debug mode I see the value is empty (e.g. {}).

Is there a way to overcome this?

I'd appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are capturing in the variable, is not the exit code. It is the output value (StandardOutput).

For getting the exit code, what you have to do is, in the command arguments, add the below suffix

```
Executable: cmd.exe
Arguments: /C mycmd_with_parameters;echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

%errorlevel% will be having the exit code of the executable. You are outputting that to standard output. [More info on %Errorlevel%](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html)

**There is one caveat:**

> When an external command is run by CMD.EXE, it will detect the
> executable's Return or Exit Code and set the ERRORLEVEL to match. In
> most cases the ERRORLEVEL will be the same as the Exit code, but there
> are some cases where they can differ.
>
> An Exit Code can be detected directly with redirection operators
> (Success/Failure ignoring the ERRORLEVEL) this can often be more
> reliable than trusting the ERRORLEVEL which may or may not have been
> set correctly.

Now, you will get the exitcode of the executable as standardoutput and you can capture it to the variable, as you have configured.

Answer (score 0):

The **StandardOutputVariable** of an Execute Process Task contains the terminal output. So, if you are using a bash executable, all `ECHO` results should be saved on that variable.

You can check the variable values [during runtime](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2019/12/21/checking-ssis-variable-values-during-runtime/) debug.